# How do i Make a load more button

Tags: javascript, php, html

I wake to to Create a button.. Everytime the user click on The load more buttom i want it to keep The number is ++ so on and so on.. But so far it gotten to ten i dont know how to make it load more without stopping everytime the user click on the button
heres the code i have so far

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>

        <p>Click the button to loop through a block of code five times.</p>
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Load More</button>
        <p id="demo"></p>
        <script>
            function myFunction() {
                var y="";
                for (var i=0;i<10;i++) {
                    y=y + "The number is " + i + "<br>";
                }
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=y;
            }
            var x="";
            for (var i=0;i<5;i++) {
                x=x + "The number is " + i + "<br>";
            }
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=x;
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: every time the button is clicked do you want 10 more elements, or just one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare your counter variable outside of your function for this to work. Try this: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qLY5n/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var i = 0;
    function myFunction() {
        var y="";
        for (var j = 0;j < 5;j++)
        {
            y=y + "The number is " + i + "<br>";
            i++;
        }
        var inner = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=inner + y;
    }

    var x="";
    for (;i<5;i++)
    {
        x=x + "The number is " + i + "<br>";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=x;
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean "convert to PHP format"? Do you mean achieve the same task in PHP? Or do you mean include that as JavaScript code in PHP? Remember, PHP is a server-side language and it's all processed on the server before the HTTP response is sent back to the client's browser.

Comment: I mean i chieave the same task in php . i tried changing the vars to $varname and it didnt work

Comment: Like I said before, PHP is a server-side language and all of its code is processed BEFORE the page is returned to your browser. What that means is you can't "directly" change information on the page. I put directly in quotes because you can by using AJAX to get the data from a PHP script and use JS to display it. There's no point in doing this in PHP though. Why do you want to use PHP for this task?

Comment: im trying to create a load more button through xml files, i thought i could do it with java then i learned that java cant access your server. so i thought maybe if i can process this code with php  i could create the load more button... Im new to php

Answer (score 1):

in the code you posted x and y only exist inside your function `myFunction` if you want to keep the state of x and y you need to move the declaration of x and y outside of your function like so

```
...
<script>
// declare x and y outside of myFunction
// this makes them javascript globals (which is considered bad practice tough)
var x = "";
var y = "";

function myFunction()
{
  for (var i=0;i<10;i++)
  // ...
  // do your stuff with x and y
}
</script>
```